# 3.3 Volts Output on 1.8 Volt Regultor

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, noise

On my circuit board, I have three different voltage regulators. I have a 5V Buck converter that goes into a 3.3V LDO and then finally 1.8V LDO. When I power the board with a USB and do not use external power, I get a good 1.8 Volts on the output of the 1.8V voltage regulator.

When I use external power, I get 3.26 Volts output on the 1.8V voltage regulator. My design is already extremely noisy, which I will be fixing on the next design. My questions is, can excessive noise on the 3.3V rail cause a voltage regulator to output 3.3 volts? Or is there something else going on here?

I am using the TLV702 Voltage Regulator. [DataSheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv702.pdf)

I have shown the waveforms on my oscilloscope of both the 1.8V and 3.3V voltages when powered with USB and External Power. I also included the measurements with the probe at 1x and 10x.
[image]
[image]

I have also included the schematic of the 1.8V Voltage Regulator.
[image]

Edit: I have added the schematic for the Buck Converter and the 3.3V Regulator
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's probably dead and failed short.

Comment: @DKNguyen I have replaced the device twice with new voltage regulators to make sure that was not the case. When I go back to USB power from external power the device still works at 1.8 Volts.

Comment: show us the circuit where the power enters up to what you have shown us

Comment: @DKNguyen I have added it to the question

Comment: where is the usb entering and where is the external power entering? what is "external power" anyways?

Comment: @DKNguyen, I have added the USB schematic. External power means when the device is battery powered and the 5V signal is regulated through the buck converter.

Comment: Well I am stumped.

Comment: What are the other voltages when powered from "external power"?

Comment: @MattYoung. The Buck Converter is giving out 5.005 Volts and the 3.3V Voltage Regulator gives out 3.289V. The 1.8V Voltage Regulator gives out 3.265V. These values are all extremely noisy when measured with the oscilloscope.

Comment: What happens if you disconnect the EN pin on the TLV02 and connect it to ground instead? Do you still get 3.3V on the output instead of 0V? Lift the pin 3 and touch a steel probe or tweezers to short pin 2 and 3 together. It almost seems like the TLV702 is in dropout mode, but I don't know what would be causing it to do that.

Comment: And the 3.3V LDO is a....? Can you show us your PCB layout?

Comment: @DKNguyen I disconnected the en and left it floating. 0 Volts but still pretty noisy. I then tried to short EN and GND. It was again another noisy 0 volts but it would jump up to 3.3V sometimes. Though it could have just been my not so steady hands shorting other pins I wasn't supposed to. Bruce the 3.3V LDO I am using is the NCP1117.

Answer (score 2):

The 3.3V regulator<sup>(1)</sup> (NCP1117 as commented) is missing its output capacitor.

For the output capacitor of the NCP1117 applies:

> Frequency compensation for the regulator is provided by capacitor C<sub>out</sub> and **its use is mandatory to ensure output stability**. A minimum capacitance value of 4.7μF with an equivalent series resistance (ESR) that is within the limits of 33 mΩ  (typ) to 2.2Ω is required. See Figures 12 and 13. The capacitor type can be ceramic, tantalum, or aluminum electrolytic as long as it meets the minimum capacitance value and ESR limits over the circuit’s entire operating temperature range.

[NCP1117 of On Semi](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCP1117-D.PDF)

Maybe you could put a SMD capacitor on top of the legs of the NCP1117. Or you could replace C14 and put the 100nF cap on top of the legs of the TLV702.

---

<sup>(1)</sup>Please use reference designator for **all** components.